# Matplotlib plt.plot with enumerate not working

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, enumerate

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

array = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6],[10,20,30,40,50,60],[3,4,5,6,7,8],[100,200,300,400,500,600]])

def plot(list):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    for a,i in enumerate(list.T):
        ax.scatter(i[0],i[1],c='red') # This is plotted
        ax.plot(i[2],i[3],'g--') # THIS IS NOT BEING PLOTTED !!!! 
    fig.show()

plot(array)
```

Now, I need to call `plot` several times **using different `array` lists.** So my `for` loop cannot be removed. Is there any other way to plot a dotted line apart from calling `plt.plot` instead ?

This is the plot I get:

[image]

**As you can see, I am not getting the `plt.plot(i[2],i[3],'g--')`. Why is this so ?**

But when you print the values using the same for loop:

```
In [21]: for a,i in enumerate(array.T):
    ...:     print i[2],i[3]
    ...:     
3 100
4 200
5 300
6 400
7 500
8 600
```

The values are perfectly printed. They however are not plotted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the for loop:

```
ax.scatter(array[0],array[1],c='red')
ax.plot(array[0],array[1],'g--')
```

The problem with your code is that you iterate over rows, which is fine for plotting single dots (`ax.scatter`), but not for connecting single dots (`ax.plot` with `'--'` option): at each row you only plot the line between that point and itself, which obviously doesn't show up in the graph.

Comment: I need the `for` loop for other purposes !! The above was just a minimal example.

Comment: then use the for loop where you need to, but leave the `ax.plot` call out of it... (you can always grow a list of values inside the loop, and at the end only call the `plot` function)

Comment: The `array` in my `for` loop keeps changing, I call the plot several times. So manually changing my `x` and `y` values in `plt.plot` is going to be strenuous. Is there an alternate way of plotting a dotted line using the above ?

Comment: Please show in your example what you are doing with your array (even in a simplified way) since this seems to be integral part of your problem.

Comment: I still don't see the problem. Why can't you just use my suggestion?

Comment: Since I have 5 different `array`, i.e. `array1, array2, array3` etc with different values, manually adding `plt.plot(array1[2],array1[3])` then again `plt.plot(array2[2],array2[3])` and so on is going to be difficult.. I might even extend it to 10 arrays.

Comment: You don't need too, just use a function as you did, but without a for loop! These are 2 different problems that have nothing to do with one another...

Comment: I think you misunderstood my suggestion: replace your whole `for` block with exactly the 2 lines I gave you. It should work.