# Creating line plot using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

My main goal is to create a line plot using matplotlib. But everytime, I get **scatter plot**. 
This is my example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def function():
    with open(filename) as f:
            next(f) #i want to skip first line
            for i,line in enumerate(f):
                x=line.split(',')
                a=[float (j) for j in x] #list 'a' now has float values not strings

                OY=a[2:34] #creating list which will start from index 2 

                OX=a[1] #creating list which has only values with index 1

                plt.plot(OX, OY,'-',color='red')


    plt.show()

function()
```

Unfortunately I got a scatter plot but I expected a line plot. What is wrong here? How can I change it?

Comment: Similar problem as there? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46680194/matplotlib-plt-plot-with-enumerate-not-working/46680224#46680224

Comment: > `ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a line plot by replacing...

```
OX=a[1] ## results in ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension
```

...with this...

```
OX=numpy.arange(len(OY)) ## create a linear list of indexes
```

I'm assuming your data lines follow this form...

```
2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256
```

Comment: thanks for help, i realised my mistake, OX and OY returned floats but it should it be list. I corrected it and now it's work :)